# How to compare array of dictionaries?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have an array of dictionaries whose keys could vary depending on the incoming data. For example,

```
arrayOfDict = [["default": "Accessibility", "cn": "为每个人而设计"], 
               ["br": "Acessibilidade", "hk_cn": "輔助使用", "default": "Accessibility"], 
               ["hk_cn": "輔助", "default": "Accessibility", "pl": "Ułatwienia dostępu"]]
```

1. I want to loop through each of the dictionaries to find if any key has multiple values and display that multiple values to the user and then let the user choose one of the value, remaining values has to be deleted.(For example in the above array "hk_cn" has two different values)
2. And if the multiple values are same, I want to delete one of the key. (For ex: default has same value everywhere)

So finally, I should have a single dictionary from arrayOfDict.
So final result should be : if user has chosen first "hk_cn" value.

```
["default": "Accessibility", "cn": "为每个人而设计","hk_cn": "輔助使用", "br": "Acessibilidade", "pl": "Ułatwienia dostępu" ]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**1.** Flatten out the `arrayOfDict` to get a single `Dictionary` using **`flatMap(_:)`**

```
let combinedDict = arrayOfDict.flatMap{($0)}
```

**2.** Group the `combinedDict` element based on the `key` using **`init(grouping:by:)`**

```
let groupedDict = Dictionary(grouping: combinedDict) { $0.key }
```

**3.** Get the `formattedDict` using **`mapValues(_:)`**

```
let formattedDict = groupedDict.mapValues { Array(Set($0.map { $0.value })) }
```

**`formattedDict` Output:**

```
["pl": ["Ułatwienia dostępu"], "cn": ["为每个人而设计"], "br": ["Acessibilidade"], "default": ["Accessibility"], "hk_cn": ["輔助使用", "輔助"]]
```

Now you can prompt user using the `formattedDict` and ask for which value to keep for the respective keys.

**Edit:**

As per your comment, you can use **`allSatisfy(_:)`** on `formattedDict` to check if it contains single `value` for each `key`.

```
let formattedDict = groupedDict.mapValues { Set($0.map { $0.value }) }
if formattedDict.values.allSatisfy({ $0.count == 1 }) {
    let newformattedDict = formattedDict.compactMapValues { $0.first }
} else {
    //add your code to display data in table here...
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't take the first element to construct your result. The OP wants to prompt the user to choose which value to take if there are multiple values for the same key. You need to use a Set

Comment: @PGDev Thanks for the answer, but I am stuck in two things here. 1. If the formatted dictionary doesn't have multiple values for any key, I want to convert it to dictionary of type [String : String]  2. Otherwise I am planning to display multiple values in tableview along with the key, for this how to iterate through formattedDict to check if any key has multiple values? Since this is under a for loop I am getting the error saying "NSWindow has detected excessive live window count" error

Comment: @GaganaSAchar Updated the answer for that.

Comment: In your first step you probably meant to write "Flatten out the `arrayOfDict` to get a single **`Array`**" or something similar, as the type of `combinedDict` is going to be `[(key: String, value: String)]` – an array of key-value tuples.

Comment: @PGDev yes, I am able to prompt the user when multiple values are found. Thank You!!!

Comment: @GaganaSAchar Great. Do Accept the answer if you got that working. Happy coding..